# Deactivate INFO messages for YUI3 on node.js?

Tags: javascript, logging, node.js, yui, yui3

I'm using YUI3 on node.js but I get all these INFO messages.

How do I deactivate them?

Answer (score 1):

> If the YUI instance is configured with debug set to true (**the default**), any calls to Y.log(..) **will be printed to the browser's native console if it has one**, and broadcast through the yui:log event.

Disable as follows

```
Y.config.debug = false;
```

Comment: @ajsie Y instance needs to be available

Comment: Btw. it seems that YUI3 don't require jsdom. Is this correct (it says here http://github.com/yui/nodejs-yui3 that it is dependent on it.

Comment: @ajsie If you want to know how dependency works, prefer to see YUI configurator: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/configurator/

Comment: @ajsie I will test debug property and let you know later

Comment: @arthur. now i understand more. i'm not using the console module, i think you have misunderstood my situation. here is my code: http://pastie.org/1181938. Run that code with "node file.js" and it will give you the same output as mine with INFO messages i want to deactivate.

Comment: @ajsie Edit http://jsbin.com/amova3 and let me see the logged info. I do not meet require function used by your sample